# "Enhances the durability", "Enhanced durability"

Tags: tense, definite-article

> High quality stitching enhanced durability.

I read an article about sewing and saw the above sentence. The context is about SPI (stitches per inch).

Is it necessary to add an article, "the"? Does it change the sentence's meaning if an article is used?

> 1a. High quality stitching enhanced durability.
> 1b. High quality stitching enhanced the durability.

---

Is appropriate to use "stitches" instead of "stitching"?

> 2a. High quality stitches enhanced durability.
> 2b. High quality stitches enhanced the durability

---

I'm still learning about tenses and wonder if it is correct to use present tense instead of past tense since it is conveying something factual? If it is in present tense, is it better to add an article?

> 3a. High quality stitching enhances durability.
> 3b. High quality stitching enhances the durability.

Comment: stitching and stitches are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine without any other context, i.e. the way you have written them.

**Summary**: The small difference is that the first line (in each of your examples) talks about general durability, whereas the second line would be more appropriate if talking about the durability of something in specific.

For example, `[...] enhances the durability of this shirt` would be more accurate than without `the`.

In terms of stiches or stitching, this again is a subtle difference. The former refers to the specific stiches themselves, whereas the latter refers to the stitching overall. The difference would be, for example, in whether the stiches were made of a high quality material, versus if the way the stitching was done was high quality (in terms of a qualified professional doing it).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it greatly! If I may ask further, in this context ```Stitching``` would mean ```the stitching was done was high quality``` whereas ```Stitches``` would mean ``` the stitches were made of a high quality material```?

Comment: @FlyingPenguin Yep, that's essentially what the difference is.